# Can I board an Alaskan cruise?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cruising

I am on a work visa in the USA and I also have a Canadian visa. I applied for Permanent Residence in Canada and have already done PR landing couple of days back at the U.S.A/Canada border. I plan to take the Alaskan loop cruise starting and ending in Seattle. There is a stopover in Victoria in Canada for just 4 hours.

Will I be able to board the cruise without PR status as I have not yet got my PR card and I am waiting for it.

Will I be able to board the ship without the PR card?

Comment: If your immigration visa is still not expired, I don't think you should have a problem with the cruise. I am not a 100% sure about it though. I would also bring your Confirmation of Permanent Residence document.

Comment: The issue is not so much going to be whether you can board the cruise, but how will you get back into Canada after it?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact your cruise line. There are some special provision for US/Canada cruises (also depending on type of cruise [number of stops, start and end point]).

Usually at embarkation port your passport is checked. As far I know, on worst case, you may not be able to go on land in Canada, so you will just enjoy that half day just the ship. [On some countries, just being in a ship one must have the correct document, also without going on land, Canada, as far I remember, Canada is not one of such country].

If you have Canadian visa and no PR, you can use such visa, so you should have no problems.

I do not see problems for your case. Again: you can ask the cruise line: for US there are some relaxed rules (often US citizen do not have passports, so for US departing cruises it is allowed to use other documents).

[Note: the stop on Canada is done just for taxation/operational reason: a non US-flag ship must have one foreign port. Note: "ship flag", not the country of the cruise line]